# Wait until something happens before we take action

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, gerunds, infinitives, subordinate-clauses

I have been thinking about this sentence structure for a while now, and I always wonder if it is correct whenever I use it.

1. Let's wait until we get more information **before we decide** on the next steps.
2. Let's wait until we get more information **before deciding** on the next steps.
3. Let's wait until we get more information **to decide** on the next steps.

Do those all seem equivalent? Are any of them wrong? What do you call these sorts of constructions, the ones that follow *get more information* above?

Answer (score 1):

All 3 are equivalent and correct.

> `before + pronoun + decide` = `before + deciding`

Many (but not all) verbs simply mean the same between `to V` and `V-ing`. For example, "I like to eat" is the same as "I like eating".

> `wait ... before + V-ing` = `wait ... to + V`

`wait ... to V` and `wait ... before V-ing` are simply verb phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Thease are all grammatically correct, and seem quite natural to me. Any differences of meanign are quite subtle, and in practice I would regard them as interchangeable with mo difference of meaning at all.